# Cannot create a row of size 11842 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Tags: sql-server-2016

The suspect table has 299 nvarchar(max) columns, 1 integer column and 1 nvarchar(255) column. Please do not ask me why, this is 3rd party vendor database. Anyway, according to my math, in the worst case scenario we should be well within 8060 limitation:

24x299 + 4 + 510 = 7690

Insert from external source fails with the above error during import process using vendor's import tool. Am I missing something in my calculation? Where possibly 11842 might come from? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the values in the record throwing this error?

Comment: No idea. Unfortunately the import tool I mentioned does not give much information in addition to the error itself.

Answer (score 6):

This is down to the implementation of how `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` actually store their data. If the number of bytes needing to be stored per column is less than or equal to 8000 bytes then the data will be stored in-row, if it is greater than 8000 bytes then it will be stored in LOB pages. When this happens, the the row holds a pointer to the LOB page that actually contains the data.

So, working backwards, the average length of data attempting to be stored stored in each column is:

(11842 - (4 + 510)) / 299 = 38 (approximate bytes / 19 characters)

As the value for each column is underneath the 8000 byte limit, it will attempt to store the data in-row and therefore exceed the limit for a page.

You can check out [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find out how much is actually stored in-row vs in LOB pages. Also, [SQL Hints](https://sqlhints.com/2016/05/11/differences-between-sql-server-text-and-varcharmax-data-type/) has a decent article that covers the basics.

Since you're probably stuck with this vendor database, and the data being imported, you can force off-row storage for all nvarchar(max) columns in the table with:

```
EXEC sp_tableoption 'dbo.mytable', 'large value types out of row', 1;
```

Comment: You can force off-row storage for nvarchar(max) with `EXEC sp_tableoption 'dbo.mytable', 'large value types out of row', 1;`

Comment: I suspect this option is not enabled for the OP but I should have added that as a possible solution, thank you!

Comment: Okay, I see. Obviously I had a misconception in my mind. I thought that nvarchar(max) is always stored in LOB pages and row data always stores 24 bytes pointer. Now the error kinda makes sense. I am going to try sp_tableoption as suggested and see if that fixes the issue.